# What to do about [failure] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag [failure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/failure)×23 that has no wiki excerpt.  I can think of at least two meanings for "failure": A possibly censored event to be modeled in survival analysis and  a success/failure in some kinds of experiment.

Comment: +1 Both meanings are apparent in the 23 threads with this tag.  We might consider disambiguating them, retagging the less popular one (success/failure in experiments), and giving them brief Wiki excerpts.

Comment: This is my first time bringing something like this to the attention of others. I'm not sure what to do or what is involved in disambiguating them.

Comment: The basic steps are to create a second tag; select appropriate names and/or synonyms for the old and new tags; create wiki excerpts for each; and then physically retag threads that need the less popular one, preferably at some little-used time of week (c. Sunday evening - Monday morning GMT perhaps). Sometimes in the initial stages "orphan wikis" can get detached from their tags and lost, so I often begin by copying and saving all potentially affected wikis and their excerpts. The retagging and Wikifying should be done by an expert in both subjects if possible.

Comment: We don't need a tag for success/failure in experiments (as we don't need tags like [success], [nobel-prize], [failed-phd-and-left-academia], etc.). "Failure" is too ambiguous as a tag name, and such a tag will inevitably be misused. I would say we should simply eliminate it altogether. Threads about survival analysis should be retagged as [survival].

Comment: I agree with @amoeba

Comment: Peter, the tag has been eliminated by @mdewey, feel free to mark my answer as accepted now. Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Copying my comment from above and slightly expanding:*

We don't need a tag for success/failure in experiments (as we don't need tags like `[success]`, `[nobel-prize]`, `[failed-phd-and-left-academia]`, etc.). Apart from that, even if sometimes "failure" has some statistical meaning, it is too ambiguous as a tag name, and such a tag will inevitably be misused. I would say we should simply eliminate it altogether. Threads about survival analysis should be retagged as [survival](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survival).

There are only 23 threads tagged with [failure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/failure), so it's easy to get rid of it.

Comment: It's fine with me to eliminate it.

Comment: +1. Get rid of it. (Sometimes I'm tempted to tag certain questions as "failure", but that would be a little meta on the main site, so I'll just VTC.)

Comment: Am sorting them out now.

Comment: All gone now, some re-tagged as survival and one or two other tags.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks! I pinged Peter (OP) to mark this answer as accepted.